# Mongoose, add and read back nested documents

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Ok, this is driving me insane. It should be simple... I hope. I just want to reuse a model in an array, like a recursive model definition.

Here's my model

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Post = mongoose.model("Post", {
    username : String,
    message : String,
    replies : [{
        type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : 'Post'
    }]
});

module.exports.Post = Post;
```

I've got creating post down. Here's how I'm trying to add a reply:

```
module.exports.addReply = function (id, username, message, callback) {

  var reply = new Post();
  reply.username = username;
  reply.message = message;

  Post.update(
    { _id: id },
    { $push: { replies : reply }},
    { safe: true, upsert : true},
    function (err, result) {
      if(err){
        callback(createError("Error updating post with reply"));
        return;
      }
      callback(createSuccess(reply));
    });
};
```

But when I get the Post (and it's replies) back the replies array is empty. Here's my getPost method...

```
var getPostById = function (id, callback) {
  Post
    .findOne({ _id: id })
    .populate("replies")
    .exec(function (err, post) {
      if (err) {
        callback(createError("Post '" + id + "' not found.\n" + err));
        return;
      }

      callback(createSuccess(post));
      return;
    });
};
module.exports.getPostById = getPostById;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: where is the `post` in this line coming from `post.username = username;`

Comment: ah, crap! My bad copy-ing and pasting. Should have been reply. Updated now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to save the `reply` before you push it. Remember ref just maintains a reference to the reply (with the id field, like in sql). When not saved, there is no object id to push to the replies array.

```
var reply = new Post();
reply.username = username;
reply.message = message;
reply.save(function(err, savedReply) {
    /// Post.update(...
});
```

Comment: You are right. And you even helped me save about 100 lines of code since I could reuse another method! Thanks man! Really stupid now when I see it.